# building Android java code using androidx, dagger2, butterknife doesnt build

Tags: android, dagger-2, butterknife, androidx

i've trying for 2 days with no avail, read similar posts and still cant find anything to work help highly appreciated.. best regards

and this was my last trial : **exclude module: 'support-compat'**
and all other options seems the same trying them with different combination didnt solve the problem ... 
enableing jetifier add another error .. so its disabled for the moment ..

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'XXXX'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false


            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    // the lib is old dependencies version;
    //  resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02]' // the lib is old dependencies version;
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = '2.0.0'
    def room__version = '2.1.0-alpha03'
    def firebase_version = '16.1.0'
    def dagger_version = '2.19'
    def butterknife_version = "9.0.0-rc2"


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'


    // FIREBASE
    //   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$firebase_version"
    //   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebase_version"
//    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
//    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'


    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'

//    //GLIDE
//    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
//    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    // DAGGER 2
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    // if you use the support libraries
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"


//    // Dagger 2
//    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.19'
//    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.19"
//    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.19"
//    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.19"

    //RETROFIT
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'


    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"


    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room__version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room__version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room__version"


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'

    // GSON
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    // BUTTERKNIFE
    //  implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife_version"
    //  annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknife_version"


    implementation ('com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2')***{
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
    }***
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2'


}
```

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>     Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha02] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>     is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>     Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-26:19 to override.

Comment: fixed by updating butterknife to     // BUTTERKNIFE
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed in behaviour after updating :
in build.gradle

```
// BUTTERKNIFE
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc3'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc3'
```

and setting  in gradle.properties:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true
```

---

now this is what i get :

```html
Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules jetified-guava-23.5-jre.jar (com.google.guava:guava:23.5-jre) and listenablefuture-1.0.jar (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

this is what solved the error:

```html
implementation ("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room__version")
        {
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava' //this is what fixed the library duplication error 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing is experimental.
```

Try Butterknife version 10

```
// BUTTERKNIFE
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
```